# OpenLDAP as a replica to Sun DSEE 7.0

Tags: ldap, openldap

My problems is with the capacity shortfall on my SUN DSEE 7.0 ad. The number of open sessions from the applications in my enterprise landscape is huge and the current ad servers are not able to handle the same. As of now we have two nodes of SUN DSEE running in a master-master configuration. I was thinking to have openLDAP installed either as a slave or as a replica to the master server and divert all my application traffic to openLDAP. I am not very confident whether this would work; please can anyone suggest a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

No. Replication protocols are vendor-dependent. You can, however, use a commercial synchronization server to synchronize changes between disparate LDAP server types.

Comment: Thanks Terry. Can you suggest few commercial and opensource/ freeware synchronisation options

Comment: Stack Exchange is traditionally not the place to ask for recommendations, and we do not generally recommend vendors. Because I work for such a vendor, I will not break that tradition, however, a Google search for LDAP synchronization may help.

Comment: Thanks Terry. I will keep a note of not asking for recommendations in future.